# How to set the cursor position at the end of the text in jQuery datatable textbox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using jQuery datatable to display some information in a table format. When I double click on a cell value to edit, the cell becomes a textbox which is great. But the cursor position is not at the end of the value in the textbox. The cursor is showing at 17th character position even though the value is 2 characters long. Is there any option to set the cursor position automatically at the end of the value based on the size of the value? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: You sure there is not white space in value? Seems strange that it would default to such an arbitrary location.

Comment: No, there is no white space. I also noticed that the cursor position is at 30 for a different column and all the cell values in that particular column. And the cursor position is at 17 for all the cell values for the column I mentioned in my question. It seems like it is looking at something and setting the position accordingly but I could not find what is it looking at? Thank you.